# Cookie not being saved in OctoberCMS

Tags: cookies, octobercms

I'm trying to save an item in a cookie via octobercms ajax, but the cookie is not being saved:

HTML

```html
<button
    data-request="onSaveItem"
    data-request-data="item_id: 12345">Save item</button>
```

PHP

```php
function onSaveItem() {
    $item_id = Input::get('item_id');
    Cookie::forever('saved_item', $item_id);
}
```

So, when I try to retrieve the cookie on page start, it returns `NULL`:

```php
function onStart() {
    var_dump(Cookie::get('saved_item'));
}

// output: NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cookies took me a while to understand as well. I hope I wrote this clear enough for you. Basically you aren't returning the cookie to the browser to add it to the application storage. I created an example page you can see [here](https://dev.branmuffinstudios.com/cookie/testing).

The first example is a common html form.

```html
{{ form_open({request:'onSaveItemRedirect'}) }}
    <input type="text" name="item_id" value="12345">
    <button>Save item</button>
{{ form_close() }}
```

This form sends the post information to `onSaveItemRedirect`. The key thing to note is the cookie queue. This allows the server to send the cooker in the header with the redirect.

```php
function onSaveItemRedirect() {
    $item_id = Input::get('item_id');
    $cookie = Cookie::forever('saved_item', $item_id);
    Cookie::queue($cookie);
    return Redirect::refresh();
}
```

This second example uses the AJAX API and is a bit more complicated. Notice that I am using a partial and the `data-request-complete` method. This will update the partial using a JavaScript function, `updateCookie()`, with the new cookie on AJAX complete.

```html
<h3 id="cookiePartial">{% partial 'cookie/test' %}</h3>
{{ form_ajax('onSaveItemAjax', {'complete' : 'updateCookie()' }) }}
    <input type="text" name="item_id" value="12345">
    <button>Save item</button>
{{ form_close() }}
```

Script:

```js
<script>
function updateCookie() {
    $.request('onUpdateCookiePartial', {
        update: {'cookie/test': '#cookiePartial'}
    });
}
</script>
```

PHP: Notice here that you should return a response with the cookie information. When the response is returned and completed then the AJAX API sends a request to the `onUpdateCookiePartial()`. It is good practice to return something when running an event handler; in this case `true`.

```php
function onSaveItemAjax() {
    $item_id = Input::get('item_id');
    $cookie = Cookie::forever('saved_item', $item_id);
    return Response::json(['Success'])->withCookie($cookie);
}

function onUpdateCookiePartial() {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to queue it, and make sure you are not exiting your php code afterward as cookie will be send back to client using response.

### Server side cookie you can not read it from client side, you can access and read it from server side only

```php
function onSaveItem() {
    $item_id = Input::get('item_id');
    Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever('saved_item', $item_id));
    return Response::json(['success' => true], 200);
}
```

### If you want only client side cookie you can use like this, you can not read it from server

I guess its very simple as cookie is client side you can easily manipulate it client side.

```html
<button
  data-request="onSaveItem"
  data-request-data="item_id: 12345"
  data-request-success="document.cookie = 'saved_item=222; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT';"
>
  Save item
</button>
```

**It will store cookie for maximum time like forever :)**

> You can also use other API attributes like `data-request-error` or `data-request-complete (both case error or success)` to store your cookie.

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: While this is a very good idea to set cookies like that, I went with the other answer, so I accepted that one. But this method is definitely noted and I will use it in the future. Thank you.